# How do I avoid using a global for the data behind a GUI?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, user-interface, c++11

I am writing an audio processing standalone application. I have an `AudioManager` object that wraps things to do with the engine (such as I/O device management, signal processing routing, running state). I am writing a GUI to control the `AudioManager` running in the background. Currently, every component that needs to message the `AudioManager` needs a pointer to it.

This starts to get crazy when a deeply nested object needs a pointer to the `AudioManager`, as it means that I need to pass the pointer through the constructors of GUI objects that don't directly care about `AudioManager` (only some subcomponents need to know).

I could just make `AudioManager` a singleton to avoid the boilerplate, but the information flow from the class is bidirectional, so this is probably a bad idea. I does also feel a little fishy wrapping everything into a big class, but it makes it a little easier to pass about. Is there a common pattern to avoid the mindless pointer passing?

Below is a bit of pseudocode showing some constructors highlighting the basic type of problem. I've tagged this C++11 to see if that gives any unique solutions.

```
MainWindow()
{
    am = new AudioManager();
    someWidget = new SomeWidget(am);
}

SomeWidget(AudioManager* am_) //SomeWidget does not really care about am
{
    someSubComponent = new SubThingy(am_);
}

SubThingy(AudioManager* am_) : subThingyLocalAudioManagerPtr(am_)
{
    subThingyLocalAudioManagerPtr->registerSomethingOrOther(this);
}
```

Comment: So audio manager is what kids call an audio player these days. Interesting.

Comment: So trolling is what kids do on SO these days. Interesting.

Comment: Robot is not "trolling", he's alluring to ridiculousness of calling things "managers". Which is almost always a sign of terrible design. You even got an answer that explicitly says that.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that the design is terrible - that's why I come begging :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, "SomeWidget" should take its actual dependency, "SomeThingy," not an AudioManager.

Usually when you see the whole world referencing a class it means that the class does too much. The name "XyzManager" usually indicates a problem for the same reason. (Classes should be named after what they do, and if the most specific name available that describes what it does is "Manage", then it should be separate classes)

Answer (score 2):

**[Dependecy injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)** might help. It also helps in clearing up ownership issues and you get better testability for free as it makes it easy to mock out classes.

The idea is to move all your resource allocations to the factory; your class ctors only take (smart) pointers to their immediate dependencies.

Something along these lines:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class SubThingy;

class AudioManager { 
  public:
    void registerSomethingOrOther(SubThingy* st) { };
};

// None of the ctors do resource allocation
class SubThingy { 
  public:
    SubThingy(AudioManager* am) : subThingyLocalAudioManagerPtr(am)
    {
      subThingyLocalAudioManagerPtr->registerSomethingOrOther(this);
    };
  private:
    // raw pointer, we don't own it 
    AudioManager* subThingyLocalAudioManagerPtr; 
}; 

class SomeWidget { 
  public:
    // only takes DIRECT depencies
    SomeWidget(unique_ptr<SubThingy> st) : someSubComponent(move(st)) { } 
  private:
    // SomeWidget owns someSubComponent
    unique_ptr<SubThingy> someSubComponent;
};

class MainWindow { 
  public:
    // only takes DIRECT depencies
    MainWindow(unique_ptr<SomeWidget> sw) : someWidget(move(sw)) { }
  private:
    // MainWindow owns its widgets
    unique_ptr<SomeWidget> someWidget; 
};

class Factory { // All memory allocations happen in the factory
  public:
    static unique_ptr<MainWindow> createMainWindow(AudioManager* am) 
    {
      unique_ptr<SubThingy> someSubComponent{ new SubThingy(am) };

      unique_ptr<SomeWidget> someWidget{ new SomeWidget(move(someSubComponent)) };

      return unique_ptr<MainWindow>(new MainWindow(move(someWidget))); 
    }
};

int main() {
  // not clear from the example who owns / should own the audio manager
  AudioManager* am = nullptr;

  auto mainWindow{ Factory::createMainWindow(am) };
}
```

Now, the complexity will show up in your factory class but at least the mess will be confined to one place.

If the factory becomes too big, you can split it into separate classes; or even better, **have different factories for unrelated things**: a factory producing thingies, another factory for widgets, etc.

I agree with Billy, having a manager around is the sign of a class trying to do too much and the design should be revised. Unfortunately, if the God Object lives in a third party library and you don't have control over it... :(

Comment: This is still a global though. Your global just becomes "factory" rather than the AudioManager instance.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting perspective +1

Comment: @BillyONeal Yes, I agree, having a manager around is the sign of a class trying to do too much and the design should be revised. As for the factory, you can split a big, huge factory into separate classes; or even better, have different factories for unrelated things, a factory producing thingies, another for widgets, etc.

Comment: @learnvst I have significantly revised my answer, please read it. Hope this helps in revising your design.

Comment: @Ali many thanks for the edits. This is really helping me to redesign. The code had gotten to the stage where I was miserable to work on it, so I definitely need to go back to the theory.

Comment: @learnvst Yeah, I know the feeling... Good luck with refactoring / redesigning and happy coding!